# Query does not return records as expected

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

Bellow query give  records as expected

```
@Query("From Transaction tr where tr.account.bankCustomer.customer.rokaId=?1 and tr.account.accountType=?2 order by createdDate desc")
List<Transaction> findTransactioForCorporate(String customerRokaId,AccountType accountType);
```

Bellow one give me record as expected.

```
@Query("From Transaction tr where tr.account.customerInvitation.owner.rokaId=?1 and tr.status !=?2 order by createdDate desc")
List<Transaction> findTransactioForCorporate(String ownerRokaId,Status status);
```

But bellow one only return records which satisfy my second query. ((tr.account.customerInvitation.owner.rokaId=?3 and tr.status !=?4))

```
@Query("From Transaction tr where (tr.account.bankCustomer.customer.rokaId=?1 and tr.account.accountType=?2) Or (tr.account.customerInvitation.owner.rokaId=?3 and tr.status !=?4) order by createdDate desc")
List<Transaction> findTransactioForCorporate(String customerRokaId,AccountType accountType,String ownerRokaId,Status status);
```

What I'm doing wrong here.
I'm using spring data jpa 1.7,1  , Kindly help me

Answer (score 0):

You have problem with null values in joined (OneToOne mapping) fields probably users from the first query does not have customerInvitiation and this reduces your results to records from second query eg

```
select a from AppUser a where a.username is not null or a.role.name = :name
```

if I have 3 user and only one is connected with role and two have not been yet connected query will will return only one user but if I will remove `or a.role.name = :name` part which a `or` statement this query will return 3 users. For more info you can go [here](http://forum.spring.io/forum/other-spring-related/architecture/39680-hibernate-and-null-valued-relationships).

Comment: Still I can't figure out a solution for this.